# Add new email to login credentials

Tags: support, login

I have created my account using Gmail and now it's blocked at my workplace. I tried to add another login in "My Logins" but the options shown there are also blocked.

I want to add my work email to login but there is no option to enter custom email.

So

- How to add my email to login?

or

- Do I need to create new account with my new email and request a merge with older account?

Comment: create a [StackId](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) & login using that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to you profile and:

1. Click on **my logins**
2. Click on **add more logins...**

You'll be able to add logins there.

[image]

It only accepts some popular logins (such as facebook, Google, etc). At worst, you can always create a Stack Exchange login and use that.

Comment: i tried that but when you go to that link there is not option to add your websites email option

Comment: @NullPointer: It only accepts some popular logins (such as facebook, Google, etc). At worst, you can always create an [se] login and use that.