# Can I have multiple OpenIds associated with my account ?

Tags: discussion, openid, user-accounts, login

After the debacle of google announcing the reader shutdown, I realized that if (for who knows why) google ever shut it's doors, the means by which I log into this site is gone. If I try to "login" via the yahoo or stack exchange options for my "drivers license" will Stack Exchange know who I am, or have I lost all my street cred on all my stackexchange logins? Is there a way to "add" an authentication provider to my account? (Suppose I normally login via Google, but an option is given after that to "link" additional drivers license accounts, this way if one goes down I'm not locked out).

Ultimately will I lose my account access if the OpenID provider I primarily use shuts down?

Comment: Go to you account page. Click on `my logins`. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166067/add-new-email-to-login-credentials

Comment: @Oded isn't this question dupe of the one you mentioned?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yep. I am not so good with close as duplicate... Need practice.

Comment: @Oded lol! And here I am afraid I missed something hence avoiding to cast my vote... :-)

Comment: I searched OpenAuth and drivers license and didn't find that one. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple OpenID providers linked to your account (it was two when the site started, this has changed a bit with the SE logins).

Alternatively if you own a domain (or a site) you can use that address as an OpenID relay to an actual OpenID provider. This way if your OpenID provider closes doors you can simply change the actual provider you are using on your site (which your own). This way you have control over your OpenID and don't actually need to install a full OpenID provider for yourself (unless you run out of OID providers to switch to, because all have closed doors).

(afaik Google's OpenID implementation doesn't allow one to use it this way, that's why I'm only using it as a secondary OpenID. My primary ID is on my own site and is delegated to MyOpenID, but other OID providers might allow this as well)

You can read about [OpenID delegation here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#delegating_authentication)