# How do I delete my SE OpenID?

Tags: support, openid

I created an account at Stack Exchange and realized that I don't need it and can use Gmail to log in instead. I tried clicking the x under my logins but it says "you can't remove your only login"

Comment: You need to [add another login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/187824) (i.e. Gmail) then you can delete the first one.

Comment: [How do I add new login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166068/216721) may be?!

Comment: @R.J - He do not want to delete his SE account. He just want to remove his SE OpenID.

Comment: @R.J - Updated.. :)

Comment: @hims056 I have my gmail connected. I can see it under "my logins"

Comment: @R.J I also deleted my account at stackoverflow but that still left my stackexchange.com account/openId alive... (i.e i can still login to https://openid.stackexchange.com/user)

Comment: Deleting your account from SO doesn't delete your *Stack Exchange* id.

Comment: So I figured out how to remove my SE open id from the "my logins". Apparently since the email I used to setup SE open id and gmail are the same email it thought I was deleting all logins from "my logins". However to delete the SE openID do I just let it [sit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) or someone I contact about this?

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) doesn't apply to Stack Exchange OpenID.

You can let it sit if you like. It's not really hurting anything. If you do want to remove it, though, [just let us know](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Make it clear that you want to delete the Stack Exchange OpenID account (and give us the email address it's associated with) and not your site profile.

Comment: _Triply_ important is the email address associated with the credential, it must be the _exact_ email that you used, or we probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: Adam Lear, is this the only way to remove?

Comment: @Ollie Yes, the only way to delete an SE OpenId account itself (rather than just remove it from your SE profile) is to contact support.