# How do I sign in with the same profile on Stack Exchange sites, instead of being "userXXX"

Tags: support

I'm pretty sure you used to be able to link your existing Stack Exchange profiles together, but I just had to sign up from scratch on a site (as well as this one), with some random username.

I'm already active on a couple of sites, using the same username. It wouldn't accept my Stack Exchange id when I tried, so I have no idea how to link them.

How do I do it?

Worse still, now this random id seems to have been linked with the other random id on the sci-fi site.

I just want my username back!

Comment: Try to log in with your user credentials, and the system should offer an fusion with your ID

Comment: It didn't. It told me I didn't exist, even though in the SAME browser I had a stackexchange tab open and logged in.

Comment: That's because your account didn't exist on that site.  You have to create a new account, but you enter the credentials from your existing account.

Comment: But since you already have an account now, try adding your existing credentials... see if this helps [Add new email to login credentials](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166067/add-new-email-to-login-credentials)

Comment: I entered the credentials. It told me they were wrong. thanks, but I give up - this isn't worth the work.

Comment: It's not too late. You can [still merge your accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Did you try to add the login with the link?  Failing that contact the SE team via the [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link in the footer.  Explain the situation and they will try to help.

Comment: @Sha doesn't he need both accounts on the same site to do a merge?  Or are separate accounts on separate sites also considered a merge?

Comment: @psubsee2003 good point, didn't think of that! The OP here seem to have given up though, or succeeded in merge after all. :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to your profile (meta.stackoverflow.com/users/241421/user19585) and them into, *my logins* link in the upper right side, and finally in add more logins

[image: show]

Comment: This answer is very incomplete and really doesn't completely address the OP's problem.  You should try to expand it to be a complete answer